# Apache Cordova IOS Camera plugin for visual studio 2015

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have a very crucial question , I'm using apache cordova on visual studio 2015 ,

My application uses camera plugin to transfer photo which captured to my database using base64 string and web services , also using file transferring plugin , Application runs perfectly on Android emulator and all Android devices ,

Problem is camera plugin and file transfer plugin aren't working on IOS devices while running the IOS simulator on any IOS device (Iphone 5s as example)

Note : I have connected my visual studio to My Mac (using certificate and other staff) and installed all essentials on both Mac and PC

Note 2 : I have installed this plugin as my camera plugin : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

can anyone assist me in this problem ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get the simulator working with the camera, you'll have to test using a physical device. This isn't a plugin issue, just a limitation of the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the iOS simulator does not simulate the Camera. As mentioned in the comments, you do have to use a device to test that.

This is also verified in Apple's [Simulator Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html):

> the Camera app is available only on hardware devices and cannot be
>   replicated in the simulator.